# reaction of diketone with ammonium carbonate at 100-115 degree celsius

Tags: organic-chemistry

Please explain what reaction is this and what are the products of reagent $\ce{(NH4)2CO3}$
at 100-115 C with ketone.

Comment: Which diketone? 1,2? 1,3? 1,4? 1,n? Saturated, unsaturated? Cyclic, acyclic?

Comment: sir straight chain 1,4 acyclic and i dont have anything like paal knorr.thanks anyway

Answer (score 15):

1,4-diketones are likely to give pyrroles in a *Paal-Knorr* reaction.

[image: paal-knorr]