# Reaction of a diketone

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the product when ammonium bicarbonate reacts with hexa-2,5-dione?

I thought of formation of 2 moles of NH3, water and carbon dioxide. And then the usual addition followed by elimination to the carbonyl group. But is it the case? Or will some cyclic compound result?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this (http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/reaction-of-diketone-with-ammonium-carbonate-at-100-115-degree-celsius) answer given by Klaus.

Answer (score -1):

Ketones react with NH3.

R2C=O -> R2C=NH. Hexa-2,5-dione has two carbonyl groups so it leads to cyclic compound. Check Paal–Knorr synthesis in Wikipedia to know the answer.

Comment: The reagent is ammonium bicarbonate, not ammonia. How does this lead to the reaction that you have suggested?

Comment: @bon Hi, bon. He doesn't specify the conditions, so I assume heating is used. At elevated temperatures (NH4)HCO3 decomposes yielding NH3. If you know the correct answer please feel free to  post it.